# strange page displaying after clicking add to cart button

Tags: addtocart, product-view

please visit this link and click on "add to cart" button

http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp3/index.php/petals-paper-quilling-finger-puppets.html

it will give strange page, but the item  is added to cart, if you press back button,

you can see the item is added to cart

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: it is because your style.css is not loading

Comment: What i suggest remove CDN for while from admin and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime problem is due some server restriction some backend and frontend functionality got stop working. Some of the issue like

1. Getting error and success message after reloading page
2. Admin grid insert, update delete not working.

In, your case i think it was CDN. Hope it help other.